# How to use the CIFaceBalance filter?

Tags: ios, core-image, cifilter

I've got this:

```
var faceBalanceFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIFaceBalance")!

faceBalanceFilter.setValue(inputImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)

faceBalanceFilter.setValue(NSNumber(value: origI), forKey: "inputOrigI")
faceBalanceFilter.setValue(NSNumber(value: origQ), forKey: "inputOrigQ")
faceBalanceFilter.setValue(NSNumber(value: strength), forKey: "inputStrength")
faceBalanceFilter.setValue(NSNumber(value: warmth), forKey: "inputWarmth")
```

and indeed things change when I modify these parameters.  Since the whole image changes tint/color (with faces possibly a bit more, but I'm not sure), I'm wondering if this is all.

In [this related documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_autoadjustment/ci_autoadjustmentSAVE.html) I read about the need to set image orientation, but I haven't found how that should be done when you have a separate CIFaceBalance filter.

Also, does anyone know what the OrigI and OrigQ parameters do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fascinating! The `CIFaceBalance` is actually not listed by the system as a "stand-alone" filter. (You can list all registered filters with `CIFilter.filterNames(inCategories: nil)`). So I guess it is intended to only be used auto adjustment filter with parameters set by the system. The parameters are also not really documented in its `attributes` dictionary...

However, it seems you can initialize it separately. The "image orientation" referenced in the documentation just means that you should make sure that faces in the image are aligned with the image's orientation (so they should not be on the side or upside down). 
You can change the image orientation with `image.oriented(.right)`, for instance, if needed. But Core Image should already orient images properly according to its metadata.

Comment: Thanks again for your insight Frank!